# Compressing all directories in current folder

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying to zip all folders in currents directory.

The result should be that each folder becomes an archive. I mean that archives should have the same structure as folders.

This is the script I wrote:

```
find ~/data_archive_dir \
 -maxdepth 1 \
 -type d \
 ! -iname "*.zip" \
 ! -iname "*.bz2" \
 ! -iname "*.gz" \
 -exec zip -r "{}" "{}" \;
```

but get old folders and archives with same name and files with full path inside them. what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for l_dir in ~/data_archive_dir/*/
do
    pushd ~/data_archive_dir/
    zip -r $(basename "${l_dir}").zip $(basename "${l_dir}")
    popd
    rm -r "${l_dir}"
done
```

this is what I wrote.